# Prove that $ \prod_{k=1}^6\left(x_k^2+1\right)=(2 a-c)^2 $

Tags: polynomials

> Consider the polynomial with real coefficients $P(x)=x^6+a x^5+b x^4+c x^3+b x^2+a x+1$, and let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_6$ be its zeros. Prove that
> $$
> \prod_{k=1}^6\left(x_k^2+1\right)=(2 a-c)^2
> $$

---

By vieta, we know that $$-a=\sum_{cyc} x_1$$ and $$-c=\sum_{cyc} x_1 x_2 x_3$$
Also, $$P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^6(x-x_i)$$ How do I proceed from here?

Comment: The given product is a symmetric polynomial in the roots of $P$. Any symmetric polynomial can be expressed as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials, which in this case are the coefficients of $P$. Wikipedia contains [a constructive proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: @Servaes so we can write $P(x)$ as other elementary symmetric polynomials, but how do we use the fact to solve the problem though? And by express, does it include product of other elementary symmetric polynomials too?

Comment: Yes, this includes products. If you read the Wikipedia page, you will find all information you need, and more. In particular, it describes in full detail a method for expressing any symmetric polynomial as a polynomial in the elementary ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the equation with $x^3$ and plug $t=x+{1\over x}$. We get an equation $$t^3+at^2+(b-3)t+c-2a=0$$

By Vietas formula we have $$t_1t_2t_3 = 2a-c$$

Let $x_1,x_2$ be solutions to $x+1/x = t_1$ and similary for other...

Then $$
\prod_{k=1}^6\left(x_k^2+1\right) = x_1x_2...x_6\cdot \prod_{k=1}^6\left(x_k+1/x_k\right)= 1\cdot t_1^2t_2^2t_3^2= (2 a-c)^2
$$

Comment: How did you get the motivation of dividing the polynomial by $x^3$ and to substitute $t=x+1/x$?

Comment: It is rather standard procedure when dealing with symmetric polynomial in one variable.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that we can split apart the product term into two factors using difference of squares:
$$\prod_{k = 1}^6 (x_k^2 + 1) = \left( \prod_{k = 1}^6 -(i - x_k) \right) \left( \prod_{k = 1}^6 -(-i - x_k) \right).$$
The negative inside both terms can be factored out and ignored because $(-1)^6$ is simply $1$. This leaves us with an expression that is simply $P(i) \cdot P(-i)$, which is assuredly real by the complex conjugate theorem. If we plug in both $i$ and $-i$ into the polynomial, the desired result falls out quite nicely to be
\begin{align*}
P(i) \cdot P(-i) &= i(2a - c) \cdot -i(2a - c) \\
  &= (2a - c)^2.
\end{align*}